# Wicket: dynamically add content without the Repeater in the AjaxRequestTarget

Tags: jquery, ajax, wicket, repeater, wicket-6

I want a large list on my screen, using Wicket.

The list contains `Panel`s with a lot of ajax/js functionality. The list tends to get long, so I build some limitations, just showing the first 10 entries. To get more entries, the user has to press a 'more' link.

However, the items are in a `ListView` (could be any repeater). If I want to add items to the repeater, Wicket forces me to add the repeater to the AjaxRequestTarget. This results is the **complete redraw** of the repeater in the browser.

I want to prevent this. I think I might be able to do it by doing this completely from jQuery / javascript; by asking the new 10 entries to be rendered in a invisible div, and then adding them to my list. This seems very un-wicked-y.

Can anyone suggest a better approach?

Comment: Have look at http://wicketinaction.com/2008/10/repainting-only-newly-created-repeater-items-via-ajax/ it might serve as a starting point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem and was able to solve it with wicket only:
Make a Class derived from `GenericPanel` (or just `Panel`) which contains:

- `IModel<Long> currentOffsetModel`
- `ListView`
- `AjaxLink`
- empty `div` (or any other placeholder element) as `WebmarkupContainer`
- LoadalbeDetechable Model to load the List for the ListView starting at currentOffsetModel

In the AjaxLink-`onClick` Method you need to replace the placeholder div
with the new Object of your custom class ("replaceWith"), set the AjaxLink visibility to false and 
the AjaxLink and the new Object to AjaxRequestTarget:

```
class EndlessListPanel extends Panel {

    WebmarkupContainer placeholder = new WebmarkupContainer("placeholder");

    ...

    AjaxLink<Void> nextListElem = new AjaxLink<Void>("next") {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            int offset = offsetModel.getObject().intValue();
            EndlessListPanel next = new NewsPanelList("placeholder",offset + 5);
            placeholder.replaceWith(next);
            setVisibilityAllowed(false);
            target.add(this, next );
        }

        @Override
        protected void onConfigure() {
            // The "if" prevents "previous" EndlessListPanel to query the LDM.
            if (isVisibilityAllowed()) {
                setVisibilityAllowed(!listing.getObject().isReachedEnd());
            }
            super.onConfigure();
        }
    };

    ...
}
```

Corresponding html:

```
<wicket:panel>

<wicket:container wicket:id="listItem"/>

<a wicket:id="next">Next</a>

<div wicket:id="placeholder"></div>

</wicket:panel>
```

Comment: This causes a tree of elements that are nested? As each endlesslistpanel get a child endlesslistpanel. How do you solve the maximum HTML element depth?

Comment: Yes, the elements are nested, but only in wicket and not in html. In my case, the component is used for a list preview. You can simply disable the AjaxLink in "onConfigure" (like in my example) anytime you want.

Comment: The html is pretty straightforward; I added it to the answer. Other approach to add elements to already existing list in Wicket would be with RepeatingView.

Comment: Ah. I totally missed the fact that the placeholder does not have to be inside the listItem in html. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a `PageableListView` and a `PagingNavigator`? This seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: It does not. I want to keep the information on screen, not navigate away